# How to prove that $R\cup S$ and $R\cap S$ are symmetric if R and S are symmetric?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question is as follows-

R and S are two symmetric relations on the same set A. Prove that $R\cup S$ and $R\cap S$ are symmetric.

I tried it like this but I can't continue it. Any help is appreciated.

Let a,b $ \in$ A s.t (a,b)$\in$R and (a,b) $\in$ S.

Since R and S are reflexive, (b,a)$\in$R and (b,a) $\in$ S

Comment: Do you mean "Since $R$ and $S$ are symmetric"?  If so, that is correct.  It shows that $R\cap S$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

Recall that $R$ is symmetric if whenever $(a,b)\in R$ then $(b,a)\in R$.

1. If $(a,b)\in R\cup S$, then $(a,b)\in R$ or $(a,b)\in S$. What can you infer from that?
2. If $(a,b)\in R\cap S)$, then $(a,b)\in R$ and $(a,b)\in S$. What can you infer from that?

Answer (score 1):

Two objects are $R\cup S$-related if they are $R$-related or they are $S$-related.
Two objects are $R\cap S$-related if they are $R$-related and they are $S$-related.

So it is clear that symmetry in $R$ and $S$ implies symmetry in $R\cup S$ and  $R\cap S$.